# css: overlapping headlines h1 in floated divs

Tags: html, css, css-float, overlapping

I have a div including three inner divs which are all floated left. This floats should represent three columns. So far, everthing's ok.

But if I add headlines  inside each of the inner divs and the headlines are to wide, the headlines will overlap.

An image will show it better than 1000 words:

[image]

(Sorry for external link. But due to I am new here I have not enough reputation points to post images :) )

My html code looks like this:

```
     <div id="content_container" class="appearance">
       <div class="column">
         <h1>My headline1111111111111</h1>
         text
       </div>
       <div class="column">
         <h1>My headline2222222222</h1>
           text
       </div>
       <div class="column">
         <h1>My headline333333333333333333333</h1>
         text
       </div>            
       <div style="clear: left;"></div>
    </div>
```

And here is my css code:

```
#content_container {
  position: relative;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33333%;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.appearance {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60%;  
}
```

The content_container on the other hand is also an inner div of another wrapper container. Don't know whether it matter in this case.

Any ideas what I could do, to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `word-break`, with which you can specify if you want to break line within a word, will do the trick:

```
.column { word-break:break-all; }
```

[**jsFiddle demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/47twV/)

You can read more about the `word-break` property **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)**.

Comment: Hello Daniel, thanks. But this will cut the word. This is no solution for me. Is it possible to wrap only whole words using this method?

Comment: @user3642823 yes there's `white-space:pre-line` which does that, but since the word can be so long that it won't fit on the next line either, you should go with @ScoreNinja 's solution if you don't want to "cut" words. His/her solution creates a scrollbar, hence preserving the whole words as they are.

Comment: Is it impossible to wrap headlines like normal texts in general? It's a non-satisfying solution for me, to make it scrollable or hide it :/

Comment: @nki you mean with hyphens? Like *Some teeeee-* [NEW LINE] *eeeext.*

Comment: @nki I hope you understand that you have to do *something*. Either: 1) hide; 2) make scrollbar; 3) break words.

Comment: I don't really need hyphenations. I mean something like this: OneWord [New line] OneWordWhichIsToLarge. Thanks :)

Comment: @nki ok, so if *OneWordWhichIsToLarge.* is wider than the container, what should happen?

Comment: it is a good question :) I have not think about it. So in this case I think hyphens would be nice :)

Comment: @nki a pure css solution with hyphens has very low cross-browser capacity. Sure about wanting just that and not just break words?

Comment: I think for this case I need to make a mobile version. I already read about media queries. It's a point that I need to think about in general. But in the non-mobile case: is there a possibility to wrap only whole words assuming the words are not larger than the container itself?

Comment: "wrap only whole words"? My current code does that. Change to `keep-all` if you want to prohibit break between a pair of characters.

Comment: @nki what language will your site be in? If you want to use hyphens, you will have to take that into consideration. You can read more about that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Sorry I missunderstood you :) By using break-all I had the following: e.g: Longwordword development --> Longwordword develo [NEWLINE] pment. Changing it to keep-all will solve this problem :) With this flag I have to following output: Longwordword [NEWLINE] development. Thank you. Sorry, I am a little bit tired. Late at night :)

Comment: @nki OK I got you! Glad it got fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`.column { overflow: hidden; }`

to truncate the header or

`.column { overflow-x: scroll; }`

to make it scrollable.